# How to create pdfs from rows in a dataset and save them

Tags: python, r, pdf, shiny, plotly-dash

Very general question here. Need ideas. I have a dataset with about 20 rows. I want to use python or R to automatically take each of these rows and create 1 pdf per row. The pdf is formatted in a particular way that I need to be able to play around with.

Imagine each row is a student's name, and I need to make a pdf "Report Card" for each student. The report card will have a designated spot that says "Math Grade" and then the value will come from the dataset.

I want to be able to hit run, and have all 20 of the pdfs save to a folder on my machine. Eventually, I may try to have this run on a server or something so it is fully automatic. The pdfs ultimately get emailed out to a distribution list.

I am very pretty familiar with R, and mildly familiar with Python. I have no experience in HTML, but is that what I need here?

Any tutorials, ideas, explanations of the process I should use would be appreciated.

I thought about using plot.ly.dash. But I think that is mostly for viewing in a web browser. I want pdfs, so I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Sounds like R Markdown and parameterized reports might be a good avenue to explore: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html

Comment: I solved this using VBA in Excel. It's working pretty well!

Comment: This what SSRS is for but I have to say it's a bit of a pain most of the time.  I'd rather have a script to run.